# Problem with hive thrift or with HiveMetastore by Apache Airflow

Tags: python, hive, bigdata, airflow, hive-metastore

We have a problem when possible trying to connect with Hive Metastore by HiveMetastoreHook in Apache Airflow
`thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: b'Error in sasl_decode (-1) SASL(-1): generic failure: Unable to find a callback: 32775'`

We googled this issue but still have not find any answer

But for temporary fix - We do REcreate our hive external table on which the issue happens and restart this task. Then after a few days this problem happens again and again and again. And we have no any idea where we need to fix.

NOTE:
This happens only on one big table ,
we have hive 3.1.0 and Airflow 1.10.5 ,
this issue reproduces from python3 cli by import airflow,
select this big table from hive is fine (data is fine too)

Full stack trace

````
[2021-06-30 18:05:41,143] {{base_hook.py:84}} INFO - Using connection to: id: our_hive_metastore_connection. Host: server_name, Port: someport, Schema: our_schema, Login: some_login, Password: None, extra: {'authMechanism': 'GSSAPI', 'kerberos_service_name': 'some_name'}
>>> hm.get_table(table_name='some_big_table', db='some_schema')
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/hooks/hive_hooks.py", line 608, in get_table
 return client.get_table(dbname=db, tbl_name=table_name)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hmsclient/genthrift/hive_metastore/ThriftHiveMetastore.py", line 2253, in get_table
 return self.recv_get_table()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hmsclient/genthrift/hive_metastore/ThriftHiveMetastore.py", line 2266, in recv_get_table
 (fname, mtype, rseqid) = iprot.readMessageBegin()
 File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.py", line 134, in readMessageBegin
 sz = self.readI32()
 File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.py", line 217, in readI32
 buff = self.trans.readAll(4)
 File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 62, in readAll
 chunk = self.read(sz - have)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/thrift_sasl/__init__.py", line 166, in read
 self._read_frame()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/thrift_sasl/__init__.py", line 180, in _read_frame
 message=self.sasl.getError())
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: b'Error in sasl_decode (-1) SASL(-1): generic failure: Unable to find a callback: 32775'```

Is anybody have some idea what we need to fix?
Appreciate for help!
````